# How to ignore class methods in the same line while debugging with Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gcc

Configuration:
     Eclipse Luna, debugging a C++ code with gcc.

Question:
Consider the code below, where I set the break point:

```
myFunction( someString.c_str() ); // << Break point is here
```

I want step-into directly to the myFunction, ignore the 'c_str()' call

Note: I am trying to avoid the obvious solution, which is to put a break point inside the the myFunction call.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the obvious solution?

Comment: I am dealing with a very large source code base, and quite often, it is not trivial to find the location of files - The issue is that if I press the 'step into' I get the assembly code (for c_str()), and for the 'new' operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what to do when the debugger hits the main line:

1. Hit 'F5: **Step Into**'

   - The debugger step into the 'c_str()' method. (You may not want that).
2. Hit 'F7 - **Step Return**'

   - The debugger will exit 'c_str()' and return to the entry point of the 'myFunction' call.
3. Hit 'F5 **Step Into**'

   - Now the debugger will go into the 'myFunction' call